# Run ansible playbook with multiple and and or options

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to run an ansible playbook with multiple tag based options (based on AWS Tags), such as the following:

**Last Names:**

- Last_Name_A
- Last_Name_B
- Last_Name_C
- Last_Name_D
- Last_Name_E

**First Names:**

- First_Name_A
- First_Name_B
- First_Name_C
- First_Name_D

So what I'm trying to do is pull any last name beginning with A, B or C and first names that start with either A or B.

I know I can run the following:

```
ansible-playbook run.yaml -e target='tag_Last_Name_A:tag_Last_Name_B:tag_Last_Name_C:&tag_First_Name_A

ansible-playbook run.yaml -e target='tag_Last_Name_A:tag_Last_Name_B:tag_Last_Name_C:&tag_First_Name_B
```

however I'd like to combine this into one line if possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex: 
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_patterns.html#using-regexes-in-patterns

play.yml

```
---
 - hosts: ~tag_(Last|First)_Name_(A|B):tag_Last_Name_C
   tasks:
    - name: debug
      debug: msg='ciao'
```

hosts

```
tag_First_Name_A
localhost
```

Run as:

```
ansible-playbook -i hosts play.yml
```

Comment: I don't see how that can work with the format I'm using. Can you provide an exact statement like I have documented above?

Comment: I just get error that it's an invalid host pattern. And when I edit it to just be hosts: ~(tag_[Last_First]_name_[A|B]) I get erroneous results.

Comment: I Changed the pattern